# Why are "subqueries used as an expression" allowed to return a SETOF something but not a TABLE?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table with some arrays of integers.

```
CREATE TABLE arrays (
  nums int[],
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO arrays VALUES
  ('{1, 5, 72}', 1),
  ('{3}', 2),
  ('{32, 6}', 3);
```

If I want to spread those array elements to separate rows, I can do it with a function that returns a SETOF INT, such as `unnest`.

```
SELECT
  id,
  unnest(nums)
FROM arrays;

-- id   unnest
-- 1    1
-- 1    5
-- 1    72
-- 2    3
-- 3    32
-- 3    6
```

But I always thought that subqueries inside a SELECT clause **had** to return a single value! Yet `unnest` is returning multiple values. Postgres just handles it by duplicating the row for each value. But if I try another subquery that returns multiple values, like this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  (SELECT a.nums[1] UNION SELECT a.nums[2])
FROM arrays a;

-- ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

That gives an error. It seems like it should be handled in an analogous manner to `unnest`. **Why is `unnest` allowed to return multiple values but not this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a PostgreSQL wart^H^H^H^Hfeature.

It is actually [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET):

> Functions returning sets can also be called in the select list of a query. For each row that the query generates by itself, the set-returning function is invoked, and an output row is generated for each element of the function's result set.
>
> [...]
>
> PostgreSQL's behavior for a set-returning function in a query's select list is almost exactly the same as if the set-returning function had been written in a `LATERAL` `FROM`-clause item instead.

Note that the behavior when there are *several* set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list has changed in v10; see the release notes.

I recommend that you don't use that and put such functions in the `FROM` list where they belong.